# Problems with switching between Wi-Fi APs (roaming)

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, 802.11n, 802.11

I had one Wi-Fi router at home but it wasn't enough to cover every room and I had another one lying around so I decided to connect them to cover more area.

The basic config is following:

```
┌───────┐    ┌────────────┐
│ modem │────┼WAN│router 1│
└───────┘  ┌─┼LAN│        │
           │ └────────────┘ 
           │ ┌────────────┐
           │ │WAN│router 2│
           └─┼LAN│        │
             └────────────┘
```

*router 1 (Edimax)*
IP: 192.168.2.1
DHCP: Enabled, IP range: 192.168.2.100-200
Static DHCP 192.168.2.2 IP lease for router 2
Wi-Fi channel: 13(11)

*router 2 (Comtrend)*
IP: 192.168.2.2
DHCP: Disabled
Wi-Fi channel: 1(3)

*both routers:*
Wi-Fi frequency: 2.4 GHz
SSID same
Password same
Auth: WPA2-PSK with AES encryption
20/40 MHz channel width (Auto)
subnet mask: 255.255.255.0

There are many more advanced settings some of which are available on one router but not on the other (or vice versa; but for the most part the Comtrend router is the more configurable one). I've tried to make the settings as uniform as possible but I'm far from proficient at this so I've just read through [wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Basic_Wireless_Settings](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Basic_Wireless_Settings), [wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Advanced_wireless_settings](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Advanced_wireless_settings) and [routerguide.net](https://routerguide.net/) and tried to change the settings according to the recommended ones or my reasoning.

Examples of unmatched settings: RIFS Advertisement, WMM - APSD, NAck, 802.11n rate, preamble type, CTS protect. I can provide more information on these on request (there are too many).

### Problems

There are problems when moving between the APs. A lot of the time the device fails to connect to the other router and disconnects altogether. Sometimes the Wi-Fi loses Internet connection (it remains connected but cannot reach Internet). I have to disconnect and reconnect to solve the problems and that is annoying.

Tested on an Android phone with Wi-Fi connectivity 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac (2.4/5 GHz)

### Questions

Is there some way to configure the routers so it could work better? What are typical causes of this behaviour?

### Answers to comments

- Channel numbers in parentheses are second channels to achieve 40 MHz width if I understand it correctly. For example ch. 1 is at 2412 MHz but the whole 1 (3) signal is 2402-2442 MHz.
- Broadcasting SSID is set on both routers
- The coverage areas of the two routers overlap (I can see both in WiFi analyzer)
- I am not sure whether the router 2 is using the same country code because on router 1 channels 1-13 are available and on router 2 only 1-7 are available.
- It is legal to use 2400.0–2483.5 MHz here (channels 1-13)
- I have WiFi analyzer app on the phone I'm troubleshooting with where the MAC address (AFAIK used as BSSID) of the connected router is visible

Comment: What are the channel numbers in parentheses? Are you publishing/broadcasting the SSID on both routers (that is, you don't have it marked as "non-broadcast" or "hidden" on either)? Do the coverage areas of the two routers overlap? Are they both publishing the same country code (and is it the same as the country code published by all other visible routers)? Are you in a region where use of channel 13 is legal? Was your client device purchased in a region where use of channel 13 is legal? (For example, channels 12-14 are not legal in the US or Canada).

Comment: Also, do you have a way to watch the BSSID change as you roam? Troubleshooting roaming problems requires careful observance of which BSSID (which AP) you're connected to at any given time.

Comment: @Spiff I've edited the question to answer your questions.